# Php Execute Query returns wrong output

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I need help I have added filters to my code, they all are working fine but only month & year filter is creating confliction, although when I print the SQL in PHPMyAdmin I'm getting the desired results but not in HTML form.

Please check my code below

```
global $wpdb;

                if(isset($_GET['datepickervalue']) && !empty($_GET['datepickervalue'])){
                    $quotecreateddate = $_GET['datepickervalue'];
                }else{
                    $quotecreateddate = '';
                }
                if(isset($_GET['quotes_vehicle']) && !empty($_GET['quotes_vehicle'])){
                    $quotes_vehicle = $_GET['quotes_vehicle'];
                }else{
                    $quotes_vehicle = '';
                }

                if(isset($_GET['quotes_departure']) && !empty($_GET['quotes_departure'])){
                    $quotes_departure = $_GET['quotes_departure'];
                }else{
                    $quotes_departure = '';
                }
                if(isset($_GET['quotes_destination']) && !empty($_GET['quotes_destination'])){
                    $quotes_destination = $_GET['quotes_destination'];
                }else{
                    $quotes_destination = '';
                }

                if(isset($_GET['quote_number']) && !empty($_GET['quote_number'])){
                    $quote_number = $_GET['quote_number'];
                }else{
                    $quote_number = '';
                }

                if(isset($_GET['quotes_length']) && !empty($_GET['quotes_length'])){
                    $quotes_length = $_GET['quotes_length'];
                }else{
                    $quotes_length = 10;
                }
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."quotes AS q LEFT JOIN ". $wpdb->prefix ."vehicles AS v ON q.vehicle = v.vehicle_id LEFT JOIN ". $wpdb->prefix ."departure AS dep ON q.departure_port = dep.departure_id LEFT JOIN ". $wpdb->prefix ."destination AS des ON q.destination_port = des.destination_id " ;
                $sql .= " WHERE form_id = 1 ";

                $total_query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."quotes AS q LEFT JOIN  ". $wpdb->prefix ."vehicles AS v ON q.vehicle = v.vehicle_id LEFT JOIN ". $wpdb->prefix ."departure AS dep ON q.departure_port = dep.departure_id LEFT JOIN ". $wpdb->prefix ."destination AS des ON q.destination_port = des.destination_id ";

                $total_query .= " WHERE form_id = 1 ";




                if(isset($quotes_vehicle) && !empty($quotes_vehicle)){
                    $sql .= " AND q.vehicle = '".$_GET['quotes_vehicle']."' ";
                    $total_query .= " AND q.vehicle = '".$_GET['quotes_vehicle']."' ";
                }
                if(isset($quotes_departure) && !empty($quotes_departure)){
                    $sql .= " AND q.departure_port = '".$_GET['quotes_departure']."' ";
                    $total_query .= " AND q.departure_port = '".$_GET['quotes_departure']."' ";
                }
                if(isset($quotes_destination) && !empty($quotes_destination)){
                    $sql .= " AND q.destination_port = '".$_GET['quotes_destination']."' ";
                    $total_query .= " AND q.destination_port = '".$_GET['quotes_destination']."' ";
                }
                if(isset($quote_number) && !empty($quote_number)){
                    $sql .= " AND q.id LIKE '%".$_GET['quote_number']."%' ";
                    $total_query .= " AND q.id LIKE '%".$_GET['quote_number']."%' ";
                }
            if(isset($quotecreateddate) && !empty($quotecreateddate)){
                    $sql .= "AND DATE_FORMAT(q.created_at , '%Y-%m-%d' )  = '".$quotecreateddate."' ";
                    $total_query .= "AND DATE_FORMAT(q.created_at , '%Y-%m-%d' )  = '".$quotecreateddate."' ";
                }
                if(isset($quotes_length) && !empty($quotes_length)){
                    $sql .= " ORDER BY `id` DESC ";
                    $total_query .= " ORDER BY `id` DESC ";
                }

                echo $sql;
                if(isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])){
                    $paged = $_GET['paged'];
                }else{
                    $paged = 1;
                }
                $total              = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
                $items_per_page     = $quotes_length; 
                $offset             = ( $paged * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
                $sql .= " LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}";

                $getallquotes       = $wpdb->get_results( $sql);
```

The result I'm getting is same for all dates in HTML where I fetch using the foreach loop also the pagination count which is in total_query is showing correct but the SQL query is only showing last added entries for every dates

Thank you for help in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why are you using `$_GET['quotes_vehicle']` in your second set of `if` statements? You've already declared the variable that holds that information as evident by checking if the variable isset and not empty. You may consider shortening the second set of if statements to only `( ! empty( variable ) )` since you know it's set already in your first set of `if` where you assign values to them.

Comment: okay, now I have removed them from second if statement

Answer (score -1):

This may not solve the problem (and is not necessarily an answer), but you should consider trimming down your code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

// Set all your empty variables here. No reason to use an else statement.
$quote_created_date = '';
$quotes_vehicle     = '';
$quotes_departure   = '';
$quotes_destination = '';
$quote_number       = '';
$quotes_length      = 10;


if ( isset( $_GET[ 'datepickervalue' ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ 'datepickervalue' ] ) ) {
    $quote_created_date = esc_sql( $_GET[ 'datepickervalue' ] );
}

if ( isset( $_GET[ 'quotes_vehicle' ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ 'quotes_vehicle' ] ) ) {
    $quotes_vehicle = esc_sql( $_GET[ 'quotes_vehicle' ] );
}

if ( isset( $_GET[ 'quotes_departure' ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ 'quotes_departure' ] ) ) {
    $quotes_departure = esc_sql( $_GET[ 'quotes_departure' ] );
}

if ( isset( $_GET[ 'quotes_destination' ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ 'quotes_destination' ] ) ) {
    $quotes_destination = esc_sql( $_GET[ 'quotes_destination' ] );
}

if ( isset( $_GET[ 'quote_number' ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ 'quote_number' ] ) ) {
    $quote_number = esc_sql( $_GET[ 'quote_number' ] );
}

if ( isset( $_GET[ 'quotes_length' ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ 'quotes_length' ] ) ) {
    $quotes_length = esc_sql( $_GET[ 'quotes_length' ] );
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "quotes AS q LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "vehicles AS v ON q.vehicle = v.vehicle_id LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "departure AS dep ON q.departure_port = dep.departure_id LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "destination AS des ON q.destination_port = des.destination_id ";
$sql .= " WHERE form_id = 1 ";

$total_query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "quotes AS q LEFT JOIN  " . $wpdb->prefix . "vehicles AS v ON q.vehicle = v.vehicle_id LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "departure AS dep ON q.departure_port = dep.departure_id LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "destination AS des ON q.destination_port = des.destination_id ";

$total_query .= " WHERE form_id = 1 ";

// Now just check if your variables are empty or not.
if ( ! empty( $quotes_vehicle ) ) {
    $sql         .= " AND q.vehicle = '" . $quotes_vehicle . "' ";
    $total_query .= " AND q.vehicle = '" . $quotes_vehicle . "' ";
}
if ( ! empty( $quotes_departure ) ) {
    $sql         .= " AND q.departure_port = '" . $quotes_departure . "' ";
    $total_query .= " AND q.departure_port = '" . $quotes_departure . "' ";
}
if ( ! empty( $quotes_destination ) ) {
    $sql         .= " AND q.destination_port = '" . $quotes_destination . "' ";
    $total_query .= " AND q.destination_port = '" . $quotes_destination . "' ";
}
if ( ! empty( $quote_number ) ) {
    $sql         .= " AND q.id LIKE '%" . $quote_number . "%' ";
    $total_query .= " AND q.id LIKE '%" . $quote_number . "%' ";
}
if ( ! empty( $quote_created_date ) ) {
    $sql         .= "AND DATE_FORMAT(q.created_at , '%Y-%m-%d' )  = '" . $quote_created_date . "' ";
    $total_query .= "AND DATE_FORMAT(q.created_at , '%Y-%m-%d' )  = '" . $quote_created_date . "' ";
}

// No need to wrap this in an if statement since you are setting the value as 10 if there isn't a value.
$sql         .= " ORDER BY `id` DESC ";
$total_query .= " ORDER BY `id` DESC ";

echo $sql;
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'paged' ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ 'paged' ] ) ) {
    $paged = $_GET[ 'paged' ];
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
$total          = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
$items_per_page = $quotes_length;
$offset         = ( $paged * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$sql            .= " LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}";

$getallquotes = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Comment: I think the problem is in getting the date from database  $datetime = date('d M Y - h:i:s A', strtotime($quote->created_at));
this is showing wrong date in

Comment: @Dharman This wasn't meant to be an answer, just a cleaned up version of their code with a little safe guarding in place using WP built in sql escaping. What OP does on production is a different story. Why not write an answer that solves their issue and protects against SQL injection?

Answer (score -1):

If you get a great result on phpMyAdmin, but not on the script itself, then do `echo($sql); die($sql);` and verify that the sql queries are the same.

On the pages that call this page, verify, that the URL GET variables are URL encoded properly.

Finally, the variables should be sanitized properly with something like `mysql_real_escape_string();` so  that no SQL injection attacks happen when this goes live.

Comment: I did print the echo $sql, even the query is also showing correct

Comment: When I die the foreach variable then it is not showing the output which sql query is printing

Comment: I don't see any foreach, are you talking about: `$wpdb->get_results( $sql);` ? And which output is it showing, how is it different?